# What are the difference/similarities between React (app framework from Facebook) and react.js (reactive extensions for JS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently learned about Facebook/Instagram's app framework for JavaScript called "React" and wanted to look more into it. However, I found myself getting conflicting search results, as there is another library of a similar name. So, my question is this:  Are there similarities between the two, or could someone do a better job at naming?

**React**
http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html

**react.js**
http://www.reactjs.com/

Comment: As the websites already should tell you, the two share nothing but the name.

Comment: Both of those links take you to the same website.

Comment: Ah, I apologize - I never came back to update this. At the time of posting, the second link lead to a reactive extensions framework for JavaScript.

Comment: Also, I just wanted to point out that at the time I posted this question, no one seemed to know or care about React outside of Facebook, and the documentation was very sparse. I was trying to help others with the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

react.js is a language extension that lets you have automatic binding for values. The name React comes from the automatic updates of the values when one changes.

```
react( "soonChanged = undefined" );
react( "reactive = soonChanged + 5" );
react( "reactive2 = reactive * 10" );

react( "soonChanged = 10" );
// Changes the value of reactive from "undefined5" to 15
// and of reactive2 from NaN to 150
```

React on the other end is a framework to build user interfaces. The name React comes from the automatic update of the UI when some state changes.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var converter = new Showdown.converter();

var MarkdownEditor = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {value: 'Type some *markdown* here!'};
  },
  handleChange: function() {
    this.setState({value: this.refs.textarea.getDOMNode().value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="MarkdownEditor">
        <h3>Input</h3>
        <textarea
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          ref="textarea"
          defaultValue={this.state.value} />
        <h3>Output</h3>
        <div
          className="content"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: converter.makeHtml(this.state.value)
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<MarkdownEditor />, mountNode);
```

Comment: Thanks! I hope this helps other people as well.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more comparison added to above:

react.js

- can also do auto UI updating, but you need to manually code that:

  ```
   /* **syntax aren't correct but the idea eg:
       (you can find it in their doc for correct syntax) */

   react( "yourReactiveComponent = 1" )
   react( "$('body').html( yourReactiveComponent )") 

   /* now u change that variable */ 
   react( "yourReactiveComponent = 4" ) 
   /* it will automatically call that jquery function to change the html from 1 to 4 */
  ```
- it is not really a framework, just an PUBSUB event helper, that subscribe and publish on variable change
- awesome for small applications

facebook React

- this is a framework
- they will deal with a lot of cross browser issues
- they have stuff worked on optimising performance such as an virtual DOM
- has their own cool markup syntax compiler JSX and JSXtransformer, so you can write declarative HTML in a JS file and than transform it into a real JS file
- they are component focus, so you will have both js and html that related to one component managed within their own code block, making it so much easier to change DOM stuff without switching all the time from JS to TPL and vice versa, This is the part where i love the most, I've been coding like this for some time, but never have a framework that does this for me, now I do :)

Answer (score 0):

now http://www.reactjs.com/ redirect to https://facebook.github.io/react/

It's domain seems to be acquired!

at this time `2016-08-23`, the google search result of `react.js` are all about `facebook react`

i don't know what `you said react.js` is, it seems disappeared!

from the answer above

> react.js is a language extension

i just think it seems that the old react.js is now http://reactivex.io/, i don't know right or wrong

you can see some comparison here: http://blog.getsetbro.com/js/FB-react-vs-reactiveJS-vs-ractiveJS-vs-reactiveUI-vs-reactiveX.html